# condition for textbox leave or not in c# desktop application

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox, event-handling, desktop-application

Is there any possible way to give condition that textbox focus is leave or not in any event

I tried following code but getting error

```
if (txt_partybillno.Leave == true)
{
    // code 
}
```

**also**

```
if (this.txt_partybillno.Leave == true)
{
    // code 
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean by… _”give condition that textbox focus is leave or not in any event”_ … ? … As you already know… `txt_partybillno.Leave == true` … will not work. The `TextBox.Leave` is an “event” and you add or remove an `EventHandler` to it like… `textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(textBox1_Leave);` … then when the focus leaves the text box, the `textBox1_Leave` event method will get executed. Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: Why would anyone ask for help about an error they are getting, and then not show the error? Makes no sense.